# Using Ubuntu without any knowledge of Linux

Tags: usability

Can I still install and use Ubuntu without any basic knowledge of a Linux operating system - do I need any background knowledge of Linux to use Ubuntu?
If so, what will be the limits of my experience?

Also, I heard from http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/ that I don't need any drivers for hardware and peripherals. Can somebody shed some light on this statement?

P.S. I don't know if these questions have been asked yet, I searched for these (maybe I didn't search hard enough), but I didn't find any.

Comment: This question may be a better fit on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) as its likely to be highly opinion based.  However, many people use Linux with little knowledge to start with.  If you are used to Windows I recommend you dual boot to start with.  Ubuntu contains a lot of hardware drivers by default so many systems just work but I always recommend you try without installing first from a USB or DVD as some hardware is not supported very well.  If you have any problems you can always ask about them before you commit to install.  If not install -- Welcome to Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Thank you Warren Hill for giving me an honest opinion. I have found  a craving for Linux lately after i read the  http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/. I just dont know where to start with. There is always some amount of doubt before moving to a completely new OS with all new kind of a UI.

Comment: There is plenty of help available if you get stuck.  If you have a specific question you can ask about it here on Ask Ubuntu or on [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+questions) and for more open ended discussions there are the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/).  We are mostly friendly and happy to offer opinions and advice whenever you need it.

Comment: Ubuntu Forums also answers specific questions. I don't see why it's necessary to refer to it only for "more open ended discussions".

Comment: Vasa1 is correct you can ask about anything on Ubuntu Forums. I consider my self suitably told off.  I personally prefer this site and Launchpad for specific questions but that's just me.

Comment: @KiranAadityaJhonny - The thing is, many new users feel driven over by the big content of infos regarding Unix/Linux - so mostly at beginning are a bit "struck" and feel overwhelmed (me too in year 2000).

Comment: Linux is pretty easy to use and definitely worth some effort. As long as you stick to the basics, you're unlikely to have any problems at all. When you start branching out by installing more optional packages, then it can become a bit more complicated, but help is available. The only things I commonly run into are proprietary Windows-only programs (like Dragon Naturally Speaking) that won't run (or won't run well) under wine (the Linux Windows emulator) and fancy hardware like the backlit keyboard on my notebook that, so far, only works in Windows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It can be a great learning experience - you can go into it as deeply as you want.

If you just want to use Ubuntu for web browsing, writing emails and documents, or any other usual thing, then it is as easy to use as windows.

But if you want to you can discover all sorts of things that are simply not available in windows - including the source code that runs the operating system. There are all sorts of high quality programs included for free, that you would have to pay for under windows.

It's not some massive technical problem that only graduates and geeks can handle, so don't worry! A couple of hours and you will feel at ease with most of it.

Also there is a huge amount of help online and a large number of people who are happy to help new users make the shift to Linux.

Comment: Thank you comrademike. I was actually captivated by the whole Open-source idea. As a life-long user of Windows, i am switching to Linux just to have a feel of a Open-source operating system. I am just beginning to read some Linux guides and understand it. Hope its not too hard. Do you have any idea of some places where i can start my journey. thank you.

Comment: I've always been a fan of just jumping in. After that, if you run into any problems, there's google.

Comment: I would say just use it and when you come across a problem come here and search the threads because a lot of common problems are easily solved, and you learn at the same time!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the community Kiran.

You can use Ubuntu without installing it, just follow [the try before installing instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).
If a driver is missing from default Ubuntu, the OS will install it. This is known as proprietary drivers. To list the drivers use the `lshw` command in Terminal.

When you install Ubuntu on a hard drive which is already occupied by Windows or Mac, be careful while choosing where to install, as I lost data while doing that.

It could be helpful if you use VMWARE or Oracle box to run Ubuntu virtually.

If any help is needed, the community is always there to help!

Comment: Its a pleasure to be here Uttam Baroi, and thank you for your concern. I will be sure to take your advice up when i am installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can install and use it without any knowledge.

The alluring aspect of Linux is its philosophy : In Linux you walk in a **free** world. There's no need to cracking, no need to a serial number, no need to prove that you've already bought a software and own it because you already own every softwares under Linux.

There are some absolutely basic command that you can do your elementary actions well with them.
commands like **sudo apt-get**, **sudo apt-add-repository** for downloading needing packages so easily, are an example.

And of course there are plenty of helpful sites (like this site) with friendly users in order to help you go through Ubuntu.

So don't hesitate and start exploring this safe and free OS.

Comment: Thank you Ali.A. That is exactly why i am changing over to Ubuntu.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm also a newbie to Ubuntu just like you. with the same goal. have a good linux

Answer (score 3):

My mom, who's not even remotely tech-oriented, prefers Ubuntu to Windows. She runs Firefox and LibreOffice and that's pretty much it, but she likes it better than Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Fear not, ;) - you can use Ubuntu without need of too much knowledge. You are on the safe side with that. But later you will feel that some knowledge cannot harm, and it is more fun, to use Linux with more tricks and else.

In this sense - here a link for you for free books - which cannot harm. It is not a must, but you can save it for later - in case you need to help yourself.:

http://itsfoss.com/5-free-ubuntu-books-for-beginners/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. use Ubuntu forums, preferably on a second machine, and eventually you will find all the answers. I personally did just this a month ago, and after crashing my systems a few times, frozen screens and seemingly impossible solutions, I found all the answers amongst the Ubuntu community. It is so refreshing not to have to pay for simple solutions, and I highly recommend that you go ahead and switch from Windows to a system that you can control yourself and does not treat you like an income source, when wanting to know more. You will also learn so much more that by only using windows, and hopefully help to promote open source software. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use Ubuntu without knowing anything about Linux. However, once you get into it, you're likely to want to learn more. It's like switching from an old mule that doesn't care much what you want to a vehicle that can be a pickup truck or an Indy racer or a jet ski as you see fit.

Little by little, you'll learn to do what interests you most.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Ubuntu and I am sure that you will enjoy it. I don't have any basic knowledge about Linux too, but recently I use Ubuntu.

If you currently use Microsoft Windows I suggest to use windows installer. It's unbelievably easy to install Ubuntu besides your Windows. Here is the link to windows installer:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Comment: Please also note that Wubi is deprecated, and is not available for the latest version of Ubuntu, 13.10 - I would recommend either using a Virtual Machine (note that speed will be noticeably slower on a VM, Oracle VirtualBox is a good Free & Open Source one which runs on all desktop OSes) or dual-booting.